# Why am I getting ORA-00937 error using only aggregate functions?

Tags: oracle, select, aggregate

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(T1.FIELD) +
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(T2.FIELD)
    FROM
      TABLE2 T2
  )
FROM
  TABLE1 T1
```

I don't see a need for group by clause in here.

Comment: This would work fine in SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Oracle

Comment: I know. But regarding the "why" it shows there is nothing inherent about the query that would prevent it.

Comment: I was trying to figure it out, but I couldn't find any explanations. It just returns me the error. Anyway, the solution below worked.

Comment: You say it returns an error, care to share it?

Comment: @TomV `ORA-00937` (in the title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate functions, but not on the same object, in a subquery, with addition. Use this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(T1.FIELD) FROM T1) +
  (SELECT COUNT(T2.FIELD) FROM T2)
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Oracle requires that an aggregate function stand alone (as opposed to being part of an expression) when there is no GROUP BY. So, since each operand in your case is the result of an aggregate function, both aggregations should be done in subqueries, [as suggested by Balasz Papp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/143614/6965).

Or you can add `GROUP BY ()` to your initial query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(T1.FIELD) +
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(T2.FIELD)
    FROM
      TABLE2 T2
  )
FROM
  TABLE1 T1
GROUP BY
  ();
```

Note, though, that the above is no longer a scalar aggregation but a vector aggregation. When there is a GROUP BY, the result set will return rows only for groups that exist in the underlying row set.

In this case, the grouping is done on an empty criterion set – that means that if the *T1* table is empty, the query will return an empty set. So, in order to get the expected result, use the above query only if *T1* is guaranteed to have rows.

Comment: Good explanation, I'd upvote if I could. Thanks Andriy.